# RMarkdown presentation with Shiny is working fine locally but couldn't open on ShinyServer

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown, rro

I have a problem with my simple `RMarkdown` document which use `shiny` widgets. I mean, it works fine locally but when I want to throw it into the ShinyServer it does not work at all. Actually it does not give any error.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: ""
date: "17.08.2015"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
```


```{r, echo = FALSE}
data(mtcars)
selectInput('name', 'Choose a cylinder:',
            choices = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)),
            selected = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1])
data <- reactive(subset(mtcars,cyl == input$name))
number <- reactive(which(sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)) == input$name))
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
renderPlot(ggplot(data(),aes(qsec, mpg))+
  geom_point(size = 6))
```
````

I use ShinyServer v1.3.0 and work on Revolution R Open 3.2.1.

```
sessionInfo()
other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1       rmarkdown_0.7       shiny_0.12.1
[4] RevoUtilsMath_3.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6      digest_0.6.8     MASS_7.3-40      mime_0.3
 [5] grid_3.2.1       R6_2.0.1         plyr_1.8.3       xtable_1.7-4
 [9] gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.2.5     stringi_0.5-5
[13] reshape2_1.4.1   proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.1      stringr_1.0.0
[17] munsell_0.4.2    httpuv_1.3.2     colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.2.6
```